# export .csv file for DB with chinese characters

Tags: csv, export, chinese-locale

I'm looking a way to export me .csv which includes some chinese characters....
It's for woocommerce,

I've more than 1000 products in total, half in english, half in chinese, The problem I have is when I export my .csv file from excel, all the Chiense character can not be read, I got some ???? instead.

I've try to export in UTF-8 and have the same problem, does anybody know a solution with any sofwares ? It will save me couple of days . . .

Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with both Chinese and Western character sets I have used Libre Office to export excel to .csv without issue. When you import .csv to LibreOffice you can specify the character set.  You will have a drop down list and the file preview will dynamically update.  This will help you find the correct set for your encoding.

It is a large download but free and cross-platform.

http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/